# Nuget dependecy resolution

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, mstest

Using MsTest.TestAdapter version 1.4.0 as an example, I am trying to understand how NuGet resolves the dependencies for this package during install.

I am not interested in the details of what version of each package will be resolved, but **where** this information is located.

If I execute the following command in an arbitrary folder:

```
nuget install -source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json MSTest.TestAdapter -version 1.4.0
```

You will see that at the end of the install there will be 50 packages installed.

Assuming these are dependencies resolved by NuGet, where does it get this dependency tree? I looked at the package information (nuspec, props, targets) and could not find any clue.

Any ideas?

Comment: The package itself explicitly states what are the direct dependencies https://www.fuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter So that NuGet can easily resolve all dependencies out.

Comment: If by "explicity states" you mean the dependencies tag on the nuget specification, then I must say I am targeting .NET 4.5 and not .NETCoreApp1.0. How this would work?

Comment: "How should this work"? .NET Framework already has all the necessary classes, and that's why it needs no other dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

> If by "explicity states" you mean the dependencies tag on the nuget specification, then I must say I am targeting .NET 4.5 and not .NETCoreApp1.0. How this would work?

Just as Lex said "The package itself explicitly states what are the direct dependencies", according to the [MSTest.TestAdapter](https://www.fuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter), we could to know the dependency tree of this package is like:

```
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp1.0">
    <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" />
    <dependency id="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" version="4.3.0" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

But if you execute the install command without option `-Framework`, nuget will restore all the dependencies of this package. That the reason why there will be 50 packages installed.

If you are targeting .NET 4.5, you should use the option `-Framework` to specify the Framework, like:

```
nuget install -source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json MSTest.TestAdapter -version 1.4.0 -Framework 4.5
```

In this case, nuget only get the dependencies for .NET 4.5. Check the document [install command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install) for some more details.

Note:

> The install command does not modify a project file or packages.config;
>   in this way it's similar to restore in that it only adds packages to
>   disk but does not change a project's dependencies.
>
> To add a dependency, either add a package through the Package Manager
>   UI or Console in Visual Studio, or modify packages.config and then run
>   either install or restore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I understand properly, it means then all 50 dependencies come from NETStandard.Library, System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener and its dependency chain, right?
When we reference MSTest.TestAdapter in a Visual Studio project, we do not see all these packages into the solution "packages" folder but we see this bunch of files on the bin directory. Where these packages are stored in the local devenv? Who makes the copy to the bin folder, since they are not referenced in the .csproj?

Comment: @IgorKondrasovas, --`If I understand properly, it means then all 50 dependencies come from NETStandard.Library, System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener and its dependency chain, right?` Yes, you are right.

Comment: @IgorKondrasovas, `Where these packages are stored in the local devenv? Who makes the copy to the bin folder, since they are not referenced in the .csproj?` If you rename the that package with .zip and unzip it, you will find the file `mstest.testadapter.props` under the folder net45. Open that .props file, you will get the content `...<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>...`, this setting copy the dll file to the bin folder.

Comment: Great! Now I just need to investigate where all these packages are stored while using Visual Studio. My project uses packages.config and these dependencies are not inside "packages" folder. Maybe some user/machine level folder...

Comment: @IgorKondrasovas, `My project uses packages.config and these dependencies are not inside "packages" folder` Check if you have any nuget.config in your solution with settting ` <add key="repositoryPath" value="OtherFolder" />`, if yes, those dependencies are not inside "packages" folder.

Comment: There is no nuget.config under my solution. The only Nuget.Config I see is located in %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config and it does not contain any repositoryPath setting.
I found the packages in question inside  global-packages folder (%userprofile%\.nuget\packages) where packages were also supposed to be (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).
My curiosity is in the fact that accordingly to that page, in case of packages.config the packages should be copied to my solution packages folder. But they are not.

Comment: I know this is details, but I think it is important to demystify.